# Cannot recognize char '!' while using topredicate in BAP

Tags: command-line, z3

I tried to use topredicate tool in bap to translate il to SMT-LIB2.

But this command returns an error:

```
./topredicate -il test.il -post "R_EBP:u32 != R_ESP:u32 -solver z3 -noopt -stp-out test.smt
```

The error is:

> A parsing exception occured while parsing "!" Fatal error: exception Lexer.LexError(line 1: Unrecognized char '!')"

Does anybody know what happened? How can I solve the problem?

PS. Anybody knows how to configure z3 in BAP? It really confuses me that it can't work while I configure it by following INSTALL.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a [BAP](http://bap.ece.cmu.edu/) issue, it looks to me that it doesn't get all the way to an SMT solver yet. Could it be that there is a `"` missing just before -solver?

```
-post "R_EBP:u32 != R_ESP:u32"
```